# how to fix the build with maven in bluemix

Tags: maven, ibm-cloud, devops

I have created a sample app (java liberty profile) on Bluemix.
When I try to build the app on Bluemix devops (I do not make changes to the code). I have this error msg :

```
Cloning the 'master' branch from repo 'https://P90MSG01:3041/git/abderrazak/sia-test-build'
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/wasdev/maven/parent/java7-parent/1.4/java7-parent-1.4.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project net.wasdev.wlp.sample:JavaHelloWorldApp:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/home/pipeline/1366b39e-02e6-4b9d-bb71-89d6d65b202d/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact net.wasdev.maven.parent:java7-parent:pom:1.4 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:80 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.44.215] failed: Connection refused and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

Finished: FAILED
```

Is there a reason ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Bluemix Status Page](https://status.ng.bluemix.net) today DevOps Delivery Pipeline service experienced some issues that should be fixed now. Some users experienced issues with pipeline jobs.
I suggest you to try again now, it should work.